# weblogic in-built distributed synchronization facility

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, weblogic

in our project we have a need for distributed synchronization where a given thread's lock state has to be synchronized on multiple nodes in a cluster so that the threads running on other nodes can wait on this locked object. I know Java does not do this across JVMs. I don't have the leverage to introduce a new 3rd party product (like Terracotta) at this stage in our project. I was wondering if Weblogic (11g) has some inbuilt facility that allows me to achieve this...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SingletonService`. It is a cluster-wide singleton in WebLogic. You should bind it to a JNDI name in `activate` method and then make lookup and call from other beans. Remember to implement your singleton service object as a plain RMI object not EJB, so make an interface extending `Remote` and add `RemoteExceptions` to methods.

For this to work you must configure WebLogic cluster *service migration* and *migration basis*.

Here is a [complete guide](http://developsimpler.blogspot.com/2012/03/weblogic-clusters-and-singleton-service.html) for implementing and configuring the service.

Comment: thanks for your input @Grzegorz - I could make a hashmap that keeps the lock information and this service could keep the hashmap synchronized/available for all nodes in the cluster. but the ONLY BIG ISSUE i see in this scheme is every call to this Singleton service is a REMOTE call - that will have pretty big overhead

I was thinking (before you suggested this SingletonService) of maintaining an oracle database table that keeps the lock information i.e which thread has a lock on which object-id  but was wary of the database call overhead. 

I think the question here is - which is faster ?

Comment: @roobanbajwa I don't know. You have to benchmark both solutions.

Comment: yea thought so :-) I was trying to avoid that .. but in this case I will proceed with this Singleton service solution and compare it with a DB solution if the need be.

Comment: I did some more research on Singleton service, and found that you cannot get a handle on this Singleton service object from another client class, leave apart being able to synchronize on its private members to achieve cluster wide cache etc. 

http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=3773

Read the comments by Prakash C. Rao on this post.

So as of now, I still haven't found solution this issue.

Comment: @roobanbajwa You can get handle only by JNDI, which indeed is a lousy solution on WebLogic. It fails when a server in cluster fails. Maybe switch from WebLogic to JBoss, it has clustered singletons. http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Clustering_Guide/beta422/html/ch05s11.html

Comment: actually its even worse than that.. even if you get a handle via JNDI, you are not guaranteed a singleton by weblogic (in that poster's experience at least). you only get a singleton behaviour from that class when you implement the functionality inside it and register it as a SingletonService in weblogic admin console. Rest it has to be executed by Weblogic. If you try to look it up via JNDI.. you won't get a clusterwide singleton behaviour, it will be a different object for each node..

Comment: I cannot switch servers either. I am very frustrated - the fact that Java or standard JEE Spec doesn't have something obvious done for this even in the year 2013. Feels like I am still living in late 90's.